# stod does not work correctly with boost::locale

Tags: c++, boost, locale, boost-locale

I am trying to use boost::locale and std::stod together in a german locale where a comma is the decimal separator. Consider this code:

```
boost::locale::generator gen;

std::locale loc("");  // (1)
//std::locale  loc = gen("");  // (2)

std::locale::global(loc);
std::cout.imbue(loc);

std::string s = "1,1";  //float string in german locale!
double d1 = std::stod(s);
std::cout << "d1: " << d1 << std::endl;

double d2 = 2.2;
std::cout << "d2: " << d2 << std::endl;
```

std::locale loc("") creates the correct locale and the output is

```
d1: 1,1
d2: 2,2
```

as I expect. When I comment out line (1) and uncomment line (2), the output is

```
d1: 1
d2: 2.2
```

The result for d2 is to be expected. As far as I understand boost::locale wants me to explicitly specify that d2 should be formated as a number and doing

```
std::cout << "d2: " << boost::locale::as::number << d2 << std::endl;
```

fixes the output to 2,2 again. The problem is that std::stod does not consider 1,1 as a valid floating point number anymore and truncates it to 1.

My question is:
why does std::stod stops working when I generate my locale with boost::locale ?

Additional information: I am using VC++2015, Boost 1.60, no ICU, Windows 10

**Update:**

I noticed that the problem is fixed when I set the global locale twice, first with std::locale("") and then with boost:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
bl::generator gen;
std::locale::global(gen(""));
```

I have no idea why it behaves this way, though!

Comment: it would save you a lot of pain in the long run, if you would check for the parsing errors by providing the idx pointer to std::stod(str, **idx**)

Comment: Yes, I do that in my real code but removed it for this simple test.

Comment: Good! I don't know how big the project is, but changing the global locale has the potential for breaking things somewhere else, it should be the last resort... but when you use std::stod you have no choice

Comment: Good point. But then again, what options do I have? My user wants the software to read in csv files with floating point numbers. So either I use the locale of the user or he would have to specify the decimal separator explicitly. In the latter case I would have to move away from using std::stod and the like completely because I of course don't want to change the global locale all the time. What seemed easy in the beginning turns out to be a mess in the end... :-(

Comment: If the speed is not the most critical requirement you may consider to use std::stringstream (look at my update). Other fast option would be boost::lexical_cast, but if I remember right it also depends on the global state (but don't take this for granded)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Long story short:** `boost::locale` changes only the global c++-locale object, but not the C-locale.  `stod` uses the C-locale and not the global c++-locale object. `std::locale`changes both: the global c++-locale object and the C locale.

---

**The whole story:** `std::locale` is a subtle thing and responsible for a lot of debugging!

Let's start with the c++ class std::locale:

```
  std::locale loc("de_DE.utf8");  
  std::cout<<loc.name()<<"\n\n\n";
```

creates the German locale (if it is available on your machine, otherwise it throws), which results in `de_DE.utf8` on the console.

However it does not change the **global** c++ locale object, which is created at the start-up of your program and is classical ("C"). The constructor of `std::locale` without arguments returns a copy of the global state:

```
...
  std::locale loc2;
  std::cout<<loc2.name()<<"\n\n\n";
```

Now you should see `C` if nothing messed up your locale before. std::locale("") would do some magic and find out the preferences of the user and return it as object, **without** changing the global state.

You can change the local state with `std::local::global`:

```
  std::locale::global(loc);
  std::locale loc3;
  std::cout<<loc3.name()<<"\n\n\n";
```

The default constructor results this time in `de_DE.utf8` on the console.
We can restore the global state to the classical by calling:

```
  std::locale::global(std::locale::classic());
  std::locale loc4;
  std::cout<<loc4.name()<<"\n\n\n";
```

which should give you `C` again.

Now, when the std::cout is created it clones its locale from the global c++ state (here we do it with the stringstreams, but it the same). Later changes of the global state does not affect the stream:

```
 //classical formating
  std::stringstream c_stream;

 //german formating:
  std::locale::global(std::locale("de_DE.utf8"));
  std::stringstream de_stream;

  //same global locale, different results:
  c_stream<<1.1;
  de_stream<<1.1;

  std::cout<<c_stream.str()<<" vs. "<<de_stream.str()<<"\n";
```

Gives you `1.1 vs. 1,1` - the first is the classical the second german

You can change the local locale-object of a stream with `imbue(std::locale::classic())` it goes without saying, that this doesn't change the global state:

```
  de_stream.imbue(std::locale::classic());
  de_stream<<" vs. "<<1.1;
  std::cout<<de_stream.str()<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"global c++ state: "<<std::locale().name()<<"\n";
```

and you see:

```
1,1 vs. 1.1
global c++ state: de_DE.utf8
```

Now we are coming to `std::stod`. As you can imagine it uses the global c++ locale (not entirely true, bear with me) state and not the (private) state of the `cout`-stream:

```
std::cout<<std::stod("1.1")<<" vs. "<<std::stod("1,1")<<"\n";
```

gives you `1 vs. 1.1` because the global state is still `"de_DE.utf8"`, so the first parsing stops at `'.'` but the local state of `std::cout` is still `"C"`. After restoring the global state we get the classical behaviour:

```
  std::locale::global(std::locale::classic());
  std::cout<<std::stod("1.1")<<" vs. "<<std::stod("1,1")<<"\n";
```

Now the German `"1,1"` is not parsed properly: `1.1 vs. 1`

Now you might think we are done, but there is more - I promised to tell you about `std::stod`.

Next to the global c++ locale there is so called (global) C locale (comes from the C language and not to be confused with the classical "C" locale). Each time we changed the global c++ locale the C locale has been changed too.

Getting/setting of the C locale can be done with `std::setlocale(...)`. To query the current value run:

```
std::cout<<"(global) C locale is "<<std::setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL)<<"\n";
```

to see `(global) C locale is C`.To set the C locale run:

```
  assert(std::setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE.utf8")!=NULL);
  std::cout<<"(global) C locale is "<<std::setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL)<<"\n";
```

which yields `(global) C locale is de_DE.utf8`. But what is now the global c++ locale?

```
std::cout<<"global c++ state: "<<std::locale().name()<<"\n";
```

As you may expect, C knows nothing about c++ global locale and leaves it unchanged: `global c++ state: C`.

Now we are not in Kansas any more! The old c-functions would use the C-locale and new c++ function the global c++. Brace yourself for funny debugging!

What would you expect

```
std::cout<<"C: "<<std::stod("1.1")<<" vs. DE :"<<std::stod("1,1")<<"\n";
```

to do? `std::stod` is a brand-new c++11 function after all and it should use global c++ locale! Think again...:

```
1 vs. 1.1
```

It gets the German format right, because the C-locale is set to 'de_DE.utf8' and it uses old C-style functions under the hood.

Just for the sake of completeness, the `std::streams` use the global c++ locale:

```
  std::stringstream stream;//creating with global c++ locale
  stream<<1.1;
  std::cout<<"I'm still in 'C' format: "<<stream.str()<<"\n";
```

gives you: `I'm still in 'C' format: 1.1`.

**Edit:** An alternative method to parse string without messing with global locale or be disturbed by it:

```
bool s2d(const std::string &str, double  &val, const std::locale &loc=std::locale::classic()){

  std::stringstream ss(str);
  ss.imbue(loc);
  ss>>val;
  return ss.eof() && //all characters interpreted
         !ss.fail(); //nothing went wrong
}
```

The following tests shows:

```
  double d=0;
  std::cout<<"1,1 parsed with German locale successfully :"<<s2d("1,1", d, std::locale("de_DE.utf8"))<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"value retrieved: "<<d<<"\n\n";

  d=0;
  std::cout<<"1,1 parsed with Classical locale successfully :"<<s2d("1,1", d, std::locale::classic())<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"value retrieved: "<<d<<"\n\n";

  d=0;
  std::cout<<"1.1 parsed with German locale successfully :"<<s2d("1.1", d, std::locale("de_DE.utf8"))<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"value retrieved: "<<d<<"\n\n";

  d=0;
  std::cout<<"1.1 parsed with Classical locale successfully :"<<s2d("1.1", d, std::locale::classic())<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"value retrieved: "<<d<<"\n\n";
```

That only the first and the last conversions are successful:

```
1,1 parsed with German locale successfully :1
value retrieved: 1.1

1,1 parsed with Classical locale successfully :0
value retrieved: 1

1.1 parsed with German locale successfully :0
value retrieved: 11

1.1 parsed with Classical locale successfully :1
value retrieved: 1.1
```

std::stringstream may be not the fastest but has its merits...

Comment: Thanks for this awesome description! Although it does not exactly answer my question, it was just a few steps to find it myself now.  Setting std::locale("") as the global locale does successfully change the C locale as you describe but not to de_DE.utf8 but to German_Germany.1252 under Windows. Setting the boost locale globally, however, does not change the C locale and that breaks stod for me! So the only solution without explicitly referring to some locale name, which seem to be different between Windows and *nix systems and which I don't know in advance anyway, is setting the locale twice